# enable/disable log levels google-chrome-devtools via settings

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I can mistake, but how to enable or disable log levels in google-chrome-devtools using devTools settings?
so for ex: when I open console window in google-chrome devtools, there is a lot of debug messages. but need only warning and errors messages.

what there are better way to disable log levels in DevTools settings?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: so, I found one way to disable all log messages from certain javascript library.

Comment: If level filter is disabled, see [Google Chrome console does not allow log level change](//stackoverflow.com/q/52730747)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Google Chrome console does not allow log level change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52730747/google-chrome-console-does-not-allow-log-level-change)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to click the Filter icon in the Console tab to expose these settings. After the panel appears, simply click on the level you want to see and your logs will filter for that level. Use <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Click</kbd> (Mac) <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Click</kbd> (Windows) if you want to select multiple, such as Errors and Warnings.

[image: Filter]

Comment: @SergeySD You're welcome. If this sufficiently solves your problem, please mark it as the accepted answer so it's clear to other users not to unnecessarily look at the question.

Comment: Is there a way to set a `Custom` level - or a custom default - so you don't have to change these every time you open a browser window?