# Google Chrome console does not allow log level change

Tags: google-chrome

My Chrome console does not allow me to adjust the log level and turn off these awful violations; the option is disabled. Why?

It looks like so:

[image]

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Click "Hide console sidebar". When the sidebar is open it controls the filters.

[image]

Comment: Why did they build it that way?!

Comment: @YuvalLevy - _great_ question.  Seems like confusing UI.  I suppose that perhaps the two controls can conflict with one another so they can't both be simultaneously disabled, but it seems like there _must_ have been a better way to organize or at least message this.

Comment: A few days ago I read this bar is going to be removed. party.

Comment: What in the world?!