# Warning "Third-party cookie will be blocked. Learn more in the Issues tab"

Tags: google-chrome, cookies, third-party-cookies

I am learning React and when running the code, I am getting a warning 'Third-party cookie will be blocked. Learn more in the Issues tab' in the console (inspect). I am getting this warning in the console every second after running the code. The number of counts of this warning is increasing continuously every second. How can I stop this?

I tried to remove this, but I did not get a correct answer.
I am expecting to remove this warning or at least stop the increasing count of this warning.

Comment: Are you getting this error in code terminal, right ? And, other than this, Are you calling any external API in your code while getting this warning ?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: As I understand, author is not looking for a cause to fix these. Most of the warnings today come from 3rd party packages and from Chrome extensions.

The only solution today is to disable "warnings" level from Google Chrome console to get rid of these new warnings. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52730747/google-chrome-console-does-not-allow-log-level-change

Comment: Google Analytics 4 seems to cause this warning, but not always. I don't see any obvious reasons why it only happens sometimes, even on the same site.

Answer (score 4):

You might want to look into this article from Google where it is mentioned more details regarding Third party cookie restriction where Chrome is going to block third party cookies at the end of this year.

https://developers.google.com/privacy-sandbox/3pcd

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There are no security settings in IITC Mobile to fix the cookie blocking.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Something similar began to happen to me as well. The issue for me was using "Open With Live Server" on my code. Not sure if you are doing this or not but figured I'd put it out there just in case someone else comes along looking for the same answers I did :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what is your application context, but I've received this warning in many of my apps where I was handling auth-cookies. The issue is that my cookies were structured like this:

[image]

It includes attributes that Google is indicating will no longer be supported.

> Cookies with the SameSite=None; Secure and not Partitioned attributes
> that operate in cross-site contexts are third-party cookies. In future
> Chrome versions, reading third-party cookies will be blocked. This
> behavior protects user data from cross-site tracking.

Using [SameSite=None](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie#samesitesamesite-value) isn't suitable for authentication cookies; you should opt for [SameSite=Lax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie#samesitesamesite-value) or [SameSite=Strict](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie#samesitesamesite-value) depending on your application's requirements.

It's crucial for your frontend and backend to be within the same domain. For instance, my frontend runs on 127.0.0.1:5173, and my backend on 127.0.0.1:5000. This same rule applies to production servers as well.

Now, I dont receive this warning anymore
[image]

See:

- https://web.dev/articles/samesite-cookies-explained

Answer (score -6):

The warning you're seeing about third-party cookies being blocked is likely related to a setting in your browser or a plugin you're using. Third-party cookies are often used for tracking purposes and some browsers have started to block them by default due to privacy concerns.

You can try any of these steps to stop:

1. **Disable third-party cookie blocking** -> From the privacy or security section of the browser's settings.
2. **Check browser Extensions**: Check Any browser extension that may be responsible for blocking Third-party cookies.
3. **Update your Browser**: Make sure you are using the latest version of the browser.

It might will fix your issue.

Comment: Was this generated by [ChatGPT](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-chatgpt-is-banned) (or similar)?