# React, Vite, Console Third-party cookie will be blocked. Learn more in the Issues tab

Tags: reactjs, vite, warnings, third-party-cookies

I found the [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78011724/third-party-cookie-will-be-blocked-learn-more-in-the-issues-tab) but it is not enough context, so i create a new one.

I'm using `React v17` and `vite v5`.

I'm gettting this warning

> "Third-party cookie will be blocked. Learn more in the Issues tab"

It cause the number of warnings increase continuosly every second like this image

[image: the warning]

And this is my `package.json` dependencies

```json
 "dependencies": {
    "@emotion/react": "^11.11.0",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.11.0",
    "@googlemaps/react-wrapper": "^1.1.35",
    "@loadable/component": "^5.15.3",
    "@microsoft/signalr": "^7.0.4",
    "@mui/icons-material": "^5.11.16",
    "@mui/material": "^5.12.3",
    "@mui/x-date-pickers": "^6.8.0",
    "async-mutex": "^0.2.6",
    "axios": "^1.4.0",
    "fast-equals": "^4.0.3",
    "fbemitter": "^3.0.0",
    "formik": "^2.2.6",
    "html-to-image": "^1.9.0",
    "jspdf": "^2.5.1",
    "jspdf-autotable": "^3.5.25",
    "lodash": "^4.17.20",
    "moment": "~2.29.4",
    "notistack": "^3.0.1",
    "numeral": "^2.0.6",
    "oidc-client": "^1.10.1",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-imask": "6.4.3",
    "react-quill": "^2.0.0",
    "react-redux": "^7.1.3",
    "react-router": "5.1.2",
    "react-router-dom": "5.1.2",
    "react-virtualized-auto-sizer": "^1.0.6",
    "react-window": "^1.8.6",
    "react-window-infinite-loader": "^1.0.7",
    "redux": "4.0.4",
    "redux-oidc": "3.1.7",
    "redux-thunk": "2.3.0",
    "source-map-explorer": "^2.5.3",
    "uuid": "^8.3.2",
    "yup": "^1.2.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/eslint-parser": "^7.21.8",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-private-property-in-object": "^7.21.11",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.18.6",
    "@types/node": "^20.10.3",
    "@vitejs/plugin-react": "^4.2.0",
    "cross-env": "6.0.3",
    "dotenv-cli": "^5.1.0",
    "eslint": "^7.32.0",
    "eslint-plugin-flowtype": "^3.13.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.24.2",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "6.4.1",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^4.2.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.32.2",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.6.0",
    "prettier": "^2.4.1",
    "serve": "^13.0.2",
    "vite": "^5.0.5",
    "vite-plugin-eslint": "^1.8.1",
    "vite-plugin-svgr": "^4.2.0",
    "vitest": "^0.34.6"
  },
```

I try to read the issues tab but i have no idea how to get rid of it. It is really anoyning. Please help me.

Comment: Find background information at https://developers.google.com/privacy-sandbox/3pcd.